# confusion in viewport transformation and geometry being stretched or squeezed

Tags: c++, opengl-es, viewport, glm-math, emscripten

i have opengles setup using emscripten to draw geomatries on a html canvas.
currently i am facing two problems,

1. i am not sure the viewport transformation is working properly or not,
2. the geometry gets squeezed or stretched on canvas resize.

the canvas is generated using this line:

```
<canvas id="webgl_main_canvas" style={{width:"100%",height:"100%"}} />
```

now with the width and height of this canvas, i setup glViewport configuration and projection matrix using:

```
glViewport(0, 0, (GLfloat)canvas_width, (GLfloat)canvas_height);
```

```
projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f), (float)(width/height), 0.1f, 1000.0f);
```

when i try to render something, the result of is a black screen [black screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwcHL.png), here the geometry is actualty there but, it is drawn somewhere far top right hence outside of the screen.

but if i set glViewport configuration using width=350 and height=150, the geometry is visible [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pfqls.png). the special thing about this dimension is that it is the default dimension of canvas as if it is created just using this:

```
<canvas id="webgl_main_canvas"/>
```

the inline style `style={{width:"100%",height:"100%"}}` only tells the canvas to occupy 100% area of its parent div.

so to summarize, creating the canvas like this `<canvas id="webgl_main_canvas" style={{width:"100%",height:"100%"}} />`:

1. if i render(after setting glViewport and projection matrix) using the actual width and height i get an black screen.
2. but if i use dimention(350,150) the geomatry is visible.

As mentioned here [viewport tranformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/opengl/glviewport), i am guessing in the first case, first the whole geomatry is stretched due to `style={{width:"100%",height:"100%"}}`and then vertices are tranfomred using the current width and height.

what could be the issue here? i want to use the actual width and height properly here.

also, for all this i am creating the view matrix using like this:

```
glm::vec3 cameraPos  = glm::vec3(0,0,1);
glm::vec3 camerafront  = glm::vec3(0, 0, -1);
glm::vec3 cameraUp  = glm::vec3(0, 1, 0);
view = glm::lookAt(cameraPos, cameraPos + camerafront, cameraUp);
```

Comment: What's up with `(float)(width/height)`?  Why the integer division followed by the float cast?  Did you mean `static_cast<float>(width)/height`?

Comment: yes, i was trying to cast the calculated aspect ratio to float type

Answer (score 0):

**Found the issue**, so basically an HTML canvas has 2 sizes, one is drawingbuffer size, and the other is the size that is being displayed through CSS, `[as mentioned here][4]`, what i was doing wrong was not setting my drawingbuffer siz, hence it was always picking the default size which was 300x150, and while setting the glViewport the width and height that i was using was wrt the CSS style, which was creating the issue.

solution is to define the the canvas like this:

```
<canvas id="webgl_main_canvas" width="1200" height="800" style={{width:"100%",height:"100%"}} />
```

here `width="1200" height="800"` is acuatlly setting the drawingbuffer size of the HTML canvas.

and whenever you want to resize, just change these values repectively.